# Problem with unique foreign key on one-to-one relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm currently facing a problem where I have two tables called `Country` and `address`.

Address has Country.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToOne
    private Country country;

    // continues with fields, getters, setters etc.
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
public class Country extends BaseEntity {
  //  continues with fields, getters, setters etc.
```

Whenever I try to save/update address with `country_id` which is already in usage I receive an error

```
`ERROR 1062: 1062: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'address.UK`
```

Is there a way to remove this constraint or to fix the relationship? Addresses can/should have "repeating" countries.

I expect to save an address with a non-unique `country_id`.

I've tries to modify relationships but it doesn't seem to work.